# Реализация backend + frontend

Tags: python, html, веб-программирование, golang, angular

Интересует вопрос, как на самом деле на нормальных сайтах работает связка frontend + backend.

Как это отделено друг от друга и как взаимодействует?Очевидно это не просто папка где всё вместе лежит(и html и php и js и т.д).

Как можно использовать разные технологии на одном и том же сайте? (на backend'e например: python,go и т.д, на фронтенде другие связки технологий.)

Интересует любая информация об этом всём. ссылки на статьи, книги, блоги ...что угодно

И по возможности (если такое существует) примеры развертывания сайтов, с разными технологиями.

Искал в интернете, но не особо нашел информацию(скорее всего не правильно искал).

Спасибо.

Comment: "Очевидно это не просто папка где всё вместе лежит(и html и php и js и т.д)."  Вообще то так оно и лежит. И это очевидно.  Когда вы открываете браузер и загружаете сайт - часть это веселой папки с js, html, css, картинками и т.д. перекочевывает вам на комп и там так и остается в кэше браузера, чтобы лишний раз не перекачивать.

Comment: Все это и есть фронтенд сайта (когда клиент это бразуер), а вот бэкенд, естественно, остается на сервере. Его задача генерить фронтенд из шаблонов html (или json'а) на каждый запрос, делать какие-нибудь хитрые вычисления для клиента (если нужно) и сохранять что-нить в БД.

Answer (score 5):

Фронтенд и бэкенд - это две разных программы, написанные на разных языках, работающие на разных компьютерах в разное время. Единственный способ их взаимодействия - это передача данных через сеть по протоколу HTTP.

Comment: есть примеры реализации?

Comment: Сотни тысяч на гитхабе и как минимум по одному в каждом учебнике..

Comment: @user366600, вот этот сайт можете посмотреть. Там в подвале есть ссылки на его исходники (бэк и фронт): https://dont-play-with-google.com/

Answer (score 1):

Да всё это про100. У вас наверняка есть статичный сайт который обращается к третьему серверу. Так вот этот сервер может быть реализован на чём угодно. Примеров масса.
Backend - это программа предоставляющая услуги посредством API  и не обязательно по HTTP протоколу. Протоколов масса и способов общения соответственно. Front-end это клиентское приложение написанное также на чём угодно и общяющаяся с backend API посредством протоколов.

Answer (score 0):

1. Надо понимать, что разделение на бек и фронт вызвано фактом существования сетей.
2. Надо понимать, что ВСЕ ресурсы относительно клиентской машины -- хранятся В СЕТИ. Вам выше неправильно ответили, что эти части могут взаимодействовать ТОЛЬКО по HTTP (подсказка: JavaScript в последних версиях и WebAssembly могут преобразовать HTTP-соединение фактически в TCP-сокет)
3. Надо понимать, что при взаимодействия фронта и бека -- важны только ИНТЕРФЕЙСЫ. Какой будет использован язык -- не важно.
4. Надо понимать, что как для фронта, так и для бека можно (но не обязательно и не рекомендуется) использовать разные языки. Если вы используете разные языки -- соответственно вы должны их знать. Но не только их, но и всю ИНФРАСТРУКТУРУ вокруг них. Это ОЧЕНЬ ДОРОГО.
5. Вы можете использовать на фронте python (через транслятор brython), можете использовать go(через WebAssembly) и даже Rust (тоже через WebAssembly). На беке уже проще -- вам не требуются специальные инструменты. И тут надо уточнять -- какая именно будет нагрузка на сервер и скорость его реакции. Если это реал-тайм игра -- делать сервер на чистом python -- сразу нет (есть способы оптимизации чистого python, но это может повлечь сложности в переносе кода на другую платформу). Лучше смотреть в сторону Go и равноценных по производительности/сложности языков.
6. Что значит НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ сайт?)) Вы можете привести пример НЕНОРМАЛЬНОГО сайта?))